# FLEX HD Capture Card Part of Video

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

When I capture video using HD capture card (1080i), only apart of video is captured, but I use USB capture (EasyCAP), it captures the full video of camera.

```
            cam=Camera.getCamera(); 
            if(cam != null){
                cam.setMode(480,360,15,true);
                cam.setQuality(0,100);
            }

            video = new Video();
            video.width = cam.width;
            video.height = cam.height;
            video.attachCamera(cam);
            vdDisplay.addChild(video);
```

How  can i capture full size of camera video and show in VideoDisplay with size is 480 x 360 ?

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: It often helps to describe things you have tried, that way we don't ask what may be pointless questions like this: I've only used webcams w/Flash (not HD capture cards), what happens if you set do `cam.setMode(1080,810,15,true)` (capture at whatever the native resolution of the device is)? Obviously that's not desirable b/c it will consume a ton of bandwidth. Note that if the camera doesn't support the capture resolution you specify, Flash tries to guess what is best. You might also fiddle w/the last param (`favorArea`) and set it to false.

Comment: I've tried setMode(1080, 810, 15 ,true) and it's consumed a lot of bandwith (~ 10 Mbps). There is only way I can try which set down the quality to improve bandwith.